# Automatic check-in in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

Every time I hit save in my visual studio 2012 It tries to check-in and most of the times it fails.!!! 
I'm using Microsoft TFS server itself.

Now my question is How can I make it stop from auto checking-in?

I tried to disable it from option->source control-> environment  but there is no option to disable the auto checking-in on saving in Saving drop down.

I want to save my project locally and check-in when ever I want and not automatically.

**I'll add a screen shot next time it happens**

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what's happening? This doesn't sound like a VS/TFS feature.

Comment: You can also check in the output window of Visual Studio and see if you can see any helpful info there.

Comment: My main question is not fixing the error. My main question is how can I disable the auto checking-in.

Comment: @Daniel - I don't think it's automatically checking in. That sound weird, which is why I ask for a screenshot of what makes you think it is checking-in automatically.

Comment: @RyanHenderson I'll add a screen shot next time it happens since it hasn't happened for like 5 days.

Answer (score 0):

I started to use TFS recently in Visual Studio 2013. I think the check-in function should be no different from Visual Studio 2012. It won't auto check-in when saving files. Have you checked "Pending Changes" -> "Included Changes" to make sure changes have been checked in?